# Python: Importing Module

Tags: python

Lets say I have a python model `fibo.py` defined as below:

```
#Fibonacci numbers module
print "This is a statement"
def fib(n):
    a,b = 0,1
    while b < n:
        print b
        a, b = b, a+b

def fib2(n):
    a,b = 0,1
    result= []
    while(b < n):
        result.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

In my interpreter session, I do the following:

```
>> import fibo
This is a statement
>>> fibo.fib(10)
1
1
2
3
5
8

>>> fibo.fib2(10)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
>>> fibo.__name__
'fibo'
>>>
```

So far so good... restart the interpreter:

```
>>> from fibo import fib,fib2
This is a statement
>>> fibo.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fibo' is not defined
>>>
```

I expected the error as I have only imported `fib` and `fib2`. But I don't understand why the statement was printed when I only imported `fib` and `fib2`.

Secondly if I change the module as:

```
#Fibonacci numbers module
print "This is a statement"
print __name__
```

What should be the expected result?

Comment: you could use a single function with `yield b`: 1. `for f in fib(n): print f` 2. `result = list(fib(n))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is expected behavior. When you import with `from X import Y`, the module is still loaded and executed, as documented in the [Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement). In fact, when you do

```
from fibo import fib
print("foo")
import fibo
```

will print `This is a statement`, followed by `foo`. The second `import` doesn't print anything as the module is already cached.

Your second module will print `This is a statement` followed by `fibo`. The module knows its own name at load time.

Comment: The second import will print only if the module is reloaded using `reload()` above the third line.

Answer (score 2):

Python has to load the whole module in order to import anything from it. Python imports the whole module into its module cache, but only the symbols you import are visible to you. (If you import a second time, it will not run; this is because the module is cached the first time it is imported.)