# Python import nuances

Tags: python, import

Could someone please shed some light on this behavior in the Python interpreter:

```
from os import path    # success
type(path)             # <class 'module'>
from path import *     # complains that no module called 'path' exists 

type(os.path)          # complains that the name 'os' is not defined, yet:
from os.path import *  # works just fine
```

As a side-question, I wonder what is the mechanism that allows a statement such as 'from os import path' to work, while yet still os is undefined? Isn't os executed at the time of the from...import, and such it should be "known" as a module? Am I right to say that keeping os out of the known names is simply a convention, intended to prevent the "polution" of the namespace with symbols that have not been imported directly (as in 'import os')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to Python 3, you'd have the same problem in Python 2. Importing of a name adds it to the namespace, nothing more.

This line:

```
from path import *
```

Means:

> "Try to find a module called `path` in any directory that is in
>   PYTHONPATH, and attempt to import all names from it to the current
>   namespace."

Since there is no such module in the current working directory, and more importantly not in any directory that's in `PYTHONPATH`, the import fails.  Note, the search doesn't search the *sub directories* of any directory that is in `PYTHONPATH`.

```
type(os.path)
```

This line fails because there is no name `os` in the current namespace (since its not imported).

> I wonder what is the mechanism that allows a statement such as 'from
>   os import path' to work, while yet still os is undefined?

Importing causes a search of paths that are defined in `PYTHONPATH` to be searched for modules; see [this article on effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) for more clarification on how importing works.

"Undefined" simply means the name doesn't exist in the namespace.

> Isn't os executed at the time of the from...import, and such it should
>   be "known" as a module?

No, when you do `from x import y` only `y` is imported, not `x`.

> Am I right to say that keeping os out of the known names is simply a
>   convention, intended to prevent the "polution" of the namespace with
>   symbols that have not been imported directly (as in 'import os')?

No, this is not true (and I hope you understand why).

Comment: Thank you. It seems I was making some wrong assumptions, especially the one that an already imported name would be "recognized" by a follow-up import that would involve it, instead of simply considering that any import actually deals with the filesystem and filesystem only. The standard Python docs (which I am familiar with) should've cleared this "chaining of imports" up for me, but for some reason my mind was insisting on making that connection.

Comment: To be thorough, when 'from x import y' is ran, x _will_ be executed (even though it _won't_ be imported!). Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993156/python-importing-module .